# How to create a unique list from a selected range of cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a list in cells `A1:A16` of foods and want to create a unique list with each item only appearing once in the list:

```
Eggs
Bacon
Hashbrowns
Baked Beans
Avocado
Coffee
Bread
Bread
Sandwhich meet
Lettuce
Tomato
mustard
mayo
Crisps
Cheese
Crackers
```

I have tried the formula
`=unique(transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(A1:A16&" "))," ")))`

but this creates a unique list and splits words such as "baked beans" into new items like so:

```
Eggs
Bacon
Hashbrowns
Baked
Beans
Avocado
Coffee
Bread
Sandwhich
meet
Lettuce
Tomato
mustard
mayo
Crisps
Cheese
Crackers
```

As you can see, "baked" and "beans" appears as two separate items. How can I make it one item in the new unique list?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working by changing what I am concatenating with.

Using a `+` to concatenate then split by the `+` I am able to avoid splitting sentences.

`=unique(transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(A1:A16&"+")),"+")))`

Comment: this does not work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/30iUK.png

Comment: You forgot to put the `&` in your formula.

Answer (score 0):

- to get a unique list of items you need only this:

  ```
  =UNIQUE(A1:A16)
  ```
- in column format:

  ```
  =TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A1:A16))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: I should have been more clear, I still want each item to be in a column format

Comment: @Stretch0 answer updated